# adjust discrete axis scale with dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that I'm trying to display with a dotplot, but it's challenging because some of my sites have much, much more data than others. Is there a way to adjust the scale on the x axis, so, in the example below, there is more space for A and B compared to C?

```
data.frame(site = c(rep("A", 6000), rep("B", 2000), rep("C", 100)),
           mass = rnorm(8100, mean = 60, sd = 5)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = site, y = mass)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = 0.11, binwidth = 1, col = "grey50")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we contrive a way to convert the discrete scale to continuous and retain grouping within `geom_dotplot`, we can get varying widths between the `site` groups.

```r
library(dplyr) # just a convenient way, many base-R options exist for this step
sites <- count(dat, site) %>%
  mutate(site_x = n[1] + c(0, cumsum(2 * n)[-n()]))
sites
#   site    n site_x
# 1    A 6000   6000
# 2    B 2000  18000
# 3    C  100  22000

left_join(dat, sites, by="site") %>%
  ggplot(aes(site_x, mass)) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(group=site), binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = 0.11, binwidth = 0.7, col = "grey50") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits=c(0, max(sites$site_x)),
    breaks=sites$site_x, labels=sites$site
  ) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

I think `binwidth=0.7` looks reasonable, play with the other "knobs" to tweak it to your preference.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion.  I'll play around with it and see what I can get to work!

Comment: You might prefer to `pmax(n, somenumber)` in `sites` to prevent a site from going too-skinny-to-be-seen @tnt

Comment: For anyone using this approach, it's definitely the best way to go, but you may have to manually choose what values to allocate to each group as trying to do it with a function proved challenging in my case.

Answer (score 1):

May be the argument [`stackratio`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_dotplot.html) could be useful?

```r
... + 
geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", 
             dotsize = 0.11, binwidth = 1, 
             col = "grey50",
             stackratio = 0.2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. I hadn't considered using this argument. but I don't think it's the best option with my dataset as it will leave quite a lot of white space around the sites that don't have much data.